# How do I solve a ValueError when running the PCHIP function on scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm, interpolation

This is part of the code:

```
# Interpolate x and y if the time gaps are < threshold (e.g. 75 ms)
    df = df.reset_index()
    currentlyAtGap = False
    currentGapStartedAtIndex = np.NaN
    durationOfCurrentGap = 0
    gap_timestamps_to_save = []

    for index, gp in df.iterrows():
        if (index % 2000 == 0 or index == 0):
            print('Processed: {}/{}'.format(index, len(df)))

        # Open gap
        if (np.isnan(gp['x_norm']) and np.isnan(gp['y_norm']) and not currentlyAtGap):  # changed scaled values to norm
            print('Opened a gap at index: {}'.format(index))
            currentGapStartedAtIndex = index
            currentlyAtGap = True

        # Decide on gap duration
        currentlyAtLastGazeP = (index == len(df) - 1)
        if (currentlyAtGap and not currentlyAtLastGazeP):
            durationOfCurrentGazeP = df.loc[index + 1, 'gaze_timestamp'] - gp['gaze_timestamp']
            durationOfCurrentGap = durationOfCurrentGap + durationOfCurrentGazeP

        # Close and interpolate gap
        if (
                (
                        # if we find a row which has an x AND y again
                        (not np.isnan(gp['x_norm']) and not np.isnan(gp['y_norm']))  # changed scaled values to norm
                        or
                        # if we are at the last row
                        currentlyAtLastGazeP
                )
                # and we are currently keeping track of a gap
                and currentlyAtGap
        ):
            # THEN: close and interpolate the gap

            # For debugging purposes
            print('Closed a gap at index: {}, with duration: {}s'.format(index, durationOfCurrentGap))
            print('Should we interpolate between index {} and index {}?'.format(currentGapStartedAtIndex, index))

            # Save the gap start and end time
            if (durationOfCurrentGap > con.valid_gap_threshold):
                # We need to save the start and end time of the gap
                # since we need it in to_lin_time_scale_and_generate_tsv
                # to NaN the x,y after interpolating is done
                startTimestamp = df.iloc[(currentGapStartedAtIndex - 1)]['gaze_timestamp']
                if (currentGapStartedAtIndex == 0):
                    startTimestamp = 0
                endTimestamp = df.iloc[index]['gaze_timestamp']
                gap_timestamps_to_save.append([startTimestamp, endTimestamp])

            # Interpolate x_norm (changed from x_scaled)
            df.loc[(currentGapStartedAtIndex - 1):index, 'x_norm'] = df.loc[(currentGapStartedAtIndex - 1):index,
                                                                     'x_norm'].interpolate()
            # Interpolate y_norm
            df.loc[(currentGapStartedAtIndex - 1):index, 'y_norm'] = df.loc[(currentGapStartedAtIndex - 1):index,
                                                                     'y_norm'].interpolate()

            # For debugging purposes (changed from y_scaled)
            print(df.loc[(currentGapStartedAtIndex - 1):index, ['confidence', 'on_surf', 'type',
                                                                'x_norm', 'y_norm']].head())

            # Reset
            currentlyAtGap = False
            durationOfCurrentGap = 0
            currentGapStartedAtIndex = np.NaN

    # Save gap indexes to file
    gap_timestamps_file = '{}/{}_gap_timestamps.json'.format(con.processed_files, pfc.PID)

    file_handle = open(gap_timestamps_file, "w")
    json.dump(gap_timestamps_to_save, file_handle)
    file_handle.close()

    # Gaps at the very start of the dataset, could not have been interpolated (because we are interpolating forwards)
    # However, these values should be interpolated as well.
    # Thus, we "fill backwards" those NaN cells at the very start with the first known value
    # In most cases (when gaps are not very short) these values will be replaced by NaNs after interpolating
    if (pd.isna(df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('x_norm')])):
        for index, gp in df.iterrows():
            if (not pd.isna(df.iloc[index, df.columns.get_loc('x_norm')])):
                df.at[0:index - 1, 'x_norm'] = np.repeat(df.iloc[index, df.columns.get_loc('x_norm')])
                df.at[0:index - 1, 'y_norm'] = np.repeat(df.iloc[index, df.columns.get_loc('y_norm')])
                break

    # Interpolate to linear time scale
    gp = to_lin_time(df, con.INTERPOLATED_FILEPATH)
    total_count_after_interpolating_to_linear_time = gp.shape[0]

    # Gaps > 75ms +/- (con.add_gap_samples) seconds near NaN
    # Now, check in the original dataframe where we have gaps (we saved this before)
    # NaN the x,y in rows where we know there is a gap with (con.add_gap_samples) seconds margin
    gap_timestamps_file = '{}/{}_gap_timestamps.json'.format(con.processed_files, pfc.PID)
    a_file = open(gap_timestamps_file, "r")
    gap_timestamps = json.loads(a_file.read())

    gp_for_calculating_interpolated_rows = gp.copy()

    for timestamp in gap_timestamps:
        gp_for_calculating_interpolated_rows.loc[(gp_for_calculating_interpolated_rows['gaze_timestamp'] > timestamp[0])
                                                 & (gp_for_calculating_interpolated_rows['gaze_timestamp'] < timestamp[
            1]), 'x'] = np.NaN
        gp_for_calculating_interpolated_rows.loc[(gp_for_calculating_interpolated_rows['gaze_timestamp'] > timestamp[0])
                                                 & (gp_for_calculating_interpolated_rows['gaze_timestamp'] < timestamp[
            1]), 'y'] = np.NaN

        gp.loc[(gp['gaze_timestamp'] > timestamp[0] - con.add_gap_samples) & \
               (gp['gaze_timestamp'] < timestamp[1] + con.add_gap_samples), 'x'] = np.NaN
        gp.loc[(gp['gaze_timestamp'] > timestamp[0] - con.add_gap_samples) & \
               (gp['gaze_timestamp'] < timestamp[1] + con.add_gap_samples), 'y'] = np.NaN

    # the amount of rows left interpolated < valid_gap_threshold
    # count how many rows we interpolated in total, and subtract the amount of rows in gaps > valid_gap_threshold

    rows_to_NaN_without_extended_gap = \
        gp_for_calculating_interpolated_rows[gp_for_calculating_interpolated_rows['x'].isnull()].shape[0]
    interpolated_rows_count = total_NaN_count - rows_to_NaN_without_extended_gap

    # Save some stats to the number_of_filtered_rows.txt
    NaN_count_with_extended_gaps = gp[gp['x_norm'].isnull()].shape[0]
    with open(text_file, "a+") as f:

        f.write('After interpolation to linear time, set position of {} rows set to NaN\n'
                .format(rows_to_NaN_without_extended_gap))
        accuracy_info['total_NaN_afterinterpolation'] = rows_to_NaN_without_extended_gap
        accuracy_info['perc_total_NaN_afterinterpolation'] = percentage

        f.write('{} interpolated rows are left in the dataset (these where < threshold of {} seconds)\n'
                .format(interpolated_rows_count, con.valid_gap_threshold))
        accuracy_info['total_interpolated_rows_left'] = interpolated_rows_count

        percentage = round(NaN_count_with_extended_gaps / total_count * 100, 2)
        f.write('Set position of {} rows ({}% of the original dataset) to NaN (after extending the gaps)\n'
                .format(NaN_count_with_extended_gaps, percentage))

    # Save the GP to a file
    gp.to_csv(con.INTERPOLATED_FILEPATH)

    print("Done! We will start outputting the dataframe to a csv file. This will take a second.")
    print('We are done! The new csv is outputted to {} and contains {} rows.'.
          format(con.INTERPOLATED_FILEPATH, len(gp)))


def to_lin_time(gp, output_file_name=con.INTERPOLATED_FILEPATH):
    first_timestamp = gp.gaze_timestamp.iloc[0]
    last_timestamp = gp.gaze_timestamp.iloc[-1]

    print('First timestamp: {}'.format(first_timestamp))
    print('Last timestamp: {}'.format(last_timestamp))

    # we find the new index
    timeIX = np.linspace(
        int(np.floor(first_timestamp)),
        int(np.ceil(last_timestamp)),
        int(np.ceil(last_timestamp - first_timestamp) * con.SF_INTERPOLATION + 1)
    )

    def interp(x, y):
        f = PchipInterpolator(x, y, extrapolate=True)

        return f(timeIX)

    gazeInt = pd.DataFrame()
    gazeInt.loc[:, 'gaze_timestamp'] = timeIX

    gazeInt.loc[:, 'x'] = interp(gp.gaze_timestamp.index, gp.x_norm)  # changed x_scaled to x_norm
    gazeInt.loc[:, 'y'] = interp(gp.gaze_timestamp.index, gp.y_norm)  # changed y_scaled to y_norm
    gazeInt.loc[:, 'gaze_point_x'] = interp(gp.gaze_timestamp.index, gp.gaze_point_3d_x)  # visual angle in x dir
    gazeInt.loc[:, 'gaze_point_y'] = interp(gp.gaze_timestamp.index, gp.gaze_point_3d_y)  # visual angle in y dir
    gazeInt.loc[:, 'gaze_point_z'] = interp(gp.gaze_timestamp.index, gp.gaze_point_3d_z)  # visual angle in z dir

    # create an "is_blink" column where values are either 0 or 1 (if interpolated blink)
    #if np.nansum(gp.type.astype(str) == 'bl0ink') > 0:
    #    gazeInt.loc[:, 'is_blink'] = interp(gp.gaze_timestamp, gp.type.astype(str) == 'blink')
    #else:
    #    gazeInt.loc[:, 'is_blink'] = 0

    # Add frame numbers
    gazeInt['frame'] = np.ceil((gazeInt['gaze_timestamp'] * con.frame_rate) + 0.00001) - 1
    gazeInt['frame'] = gazeInt['frame'].astype(int)

    return gazeInt
```

This is the error:
 `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\flava\PycharmProjects\SF_Immersion\sensoryimmersion\Utils\Smoothing_Interpolate.py", line 384, in <module> identify_gaps_and_to_linear_time(PID=pfc.PID) File "C:\Users\flava\PycharmProjects\SF_Immersion\sensoryimmersion\Utils\Smoothing_Interpolate.py", line 245, in identify_gaps_and_to_linear_time gp = to_lin_time(df, con.INTERPOLATED_FILEPATH) File "C:\Users\flava\PycharmProjects\SF_Immersion\sensoryimmersion\Utils\Smoothing_Interpolate.py", line 326, in to_lin_time gazeInt.loc[:, 'gaze_point_x'] = interp(gp.gaze_timestamp.index, gp.gaze_point_3d_x)  # visual angle in x dir File "C:\Users\flava\PycharmProjects\SF_Immersion\sensoryimmersion\Utils\Smoothing_Interpolate.py", line 317, in interp f = PchipInterpolator(x, y, extrapolate=True) File "C:\Users\flava\.conda\envs\SF_Immersion\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_cubic.py", line 234, in __init__ x, _, y, axis, _ = prepare_input(x, y, axis) File "C:\Users\flava\.conda\envs\SF_Immersion\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_cubic.py", line 54, in prepare_input raise ValueError("`y`must contain only finite values.") ValueError:`y `must contain only finite values.`

I am expecting a data file with the timestamps linearly interpolated and the corresponding x_norm, y_norm, and gaze point (x, y, and z) values interpolated with a piecewise cubic spline interpolator. At this point, I am getting ValueError and I am not sure why. I tried using absolute values, but that did not solve the problem. Prior to this code, some of the x, y, gaze point values are set to NA based on certain rules (such as confidence < 0.80).

Comment: It's complaing that the `y` array (or series) containg `inf`, or more likely `nan` elenents.  You need to examine that input more carefully.